# Yii Relations error Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have Cinema table & City table and I have relation with this tables by id.. and when I echo results i have PHP notice "Trying to get property of non-object"

What is the problem ? or I missed something ??

My Code:
**Cinema model**

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'countryCode' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TblCountry', 'country_code'),
        'city' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TblCity', 'city_id'),
        'tblCinemaMovies' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TblCinemaMovies', 'cinema_id'),
        'tblDays' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TblDay', 'cinema_id'),
        'tblShowtimes' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TblShowtime', 'cinema_id'),
    );
}
```

**City model**

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'tblCinemas' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TblCinema', 'city_id'),
        'countryCode' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TblCountry', 'country_code'),
    );
}
```

**View file:**

```
<?php echo $model->city_id->name; ?>
```

Comment: Where do you create `model` and `city_id`? Are you sure they exist?

Comment: No I dont have i think $model->city_id->name; is fase but this is work $model->city_id; result = id number.. :( how can me get 'name' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php echo $model->city->name; ?>
```

You must use `$model->city` to get the corresponding `city` of the `$model`.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you to always check if the relation does not return `null` or an `empty array`.

The following code works well with `HAS_ONE` and `BELONGS_TO` relationship types:

```
$cinema = Cinema::model()->find(); // get a cinema instance, assuming there is at least one row in the database.
$city = $cinema->city; // get the relation 
if ($city !== null) {
    // $city is a valid model
} else {
    // $city is null, the corresponding row does not exist in the database
}
```

You may also make this check without using a new variable (in this case, `$city`):

```
if ($cinema->city!==null) {
    // the relation is available
}
```

Checking if the relation does not return `null` is the best way to avoid the PHP error "trying to get property of non-object". Also, if you are stuck with similar errors, it is recommended to use functions like `var_dump()` or, even better, a debugger.

Also, notice that array keys in the array returned from `relations()` function is the property that has to be accessed to get the relation model(s):

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
         'city' => array( ... ),
         // city is the property that has to be accessed
         // Yii's conventions recommend to use 'city_id' for the foreign key column name
    );
}
```

Also note that it is good to follow Yii's conventions for naming relationships and columns to avoid using the same name for both a property and a relations - in this case, the relation will be unavailable and probably an error like "trying to access property of a non-object" will pop up when playing with the relation.

The last thing, when working with `HAS_MANY` or `MANY_TO_MANY` relationships, the relation returns an array of models even if there is only one model available and an empty array if there is nothing available.

Explanation in the docs:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#performing-relational-query

Answer (score 2):

Because the city_id is a array, in your view file, you should write the code like this

```
<?php echo $model->city_id[0]->name; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That error happens when city_id is emptied or nulled (or the value doesn't exist in the foreign table).
If you're not sure that "city_id" exists, you can check it like this:

```
CHtml::value($model, 'city.name');
```

That way you always ensure that you'll not have an Exception when the value is empty or clear